# I am using pytesseract for extracting text from Image. But it is giving me the following error

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

[This is command window showing the command running and error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jgmL.jpg)

[This is my code from where i am invoking image_to_string() function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFP6k.png)

Comment: Please do not post images, especially links.  

Include your code and resulting output as text in your post.

If your images are later lost or deleted, there is no context for the answers that may be given. Many companies block image hosting sites; if we can't see the image we can't help - and you will not get an answer.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557